# how to restrict decimal upto 2 digits only in angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

im doing some math operations using angular js . while calculating percentage/vat price showing - 0.35000000000000003 like this . i need 0.35.

0.35000000000000003. how to trim decimals after 2 digits in .

```
 <table align="center">

            <h2>Tax Calculations</h2>

            <tr>
                <td>
                     quantity : 
                </td>
                <td>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ng-model="qty"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                     unit Price : 
                </td>
                <td>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ng-model="price"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>
                     total Amount  : 
                </td>
                <td>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='{{qty * price}}' ReadOnly="true"/>
                </td>
               </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     Vat Price at 5%  : 
                </td>
                <td>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='{{(qty * price )/100  * 5}}' ReadOnly="true"/>
                </td>
               </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>
                     Total With Tax  : 
                </td>
                <td>
                 <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='{{((qty * price )/100  * 5) + (qty*price)}}' ReadOnly="true"/>
                </td>
               </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='{{(qty * price )/100  * 5 | number:2}}' ReadOnly="true"/>
```

Comment: can u tell me how to trim all decimal . i just need with out any decimal point like 10.00  -> 10

Comment: replace `number:2` with `number:0`

Answer (score 4):

Please see the angularjs example

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

By the way ,suggest not mix asp.net and angularjs code into the same tag

```
 //number with two digit
 Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:2}}</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try javascript toFixed method like below

```
{{((qty * price )/100  * 5).toFixed(2)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

angularjs document contains a very simple and pretty example. You can do this by :

```
<script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.56789;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter number: <input ng-model='val'></label><br>
  Default formatting: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span><br>
  No fractions: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span><br>
  Negative number: <span>{{-val | number:4}}</span>
</div>
```